# Calling method of applicationobject in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

in my project I have several activities and 1 application defined. The application object contains some methods some of the activities are using.

Within the activity I am calling the methods of the application object out of an inner class that extends AsyncTask. Is this correct resp. is the method of the application is also executed in the AsyncTask process?

Thanks a lot!

Neo74

Comment: Everything is correct as long as all the tests pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you are calling that method in the Asynctask.

on "doInBackground" everything you are doing will be run on a separate thread.
and on "onPreExecute/onPostExecute" will be run on the main thread(or UI thread).

The application process along with all the threads will run as long as the system is not going to kill it.

You can read more about the process life cycle here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle

Comment: Thanks! That is what I thought but I was not quite sure.